# How to upload an artifact on nexus managed proxy repository

Tags: nexus

We have our apache maven repository hosted on a server and we are using nexus to have this as a proxy repository. I want to upload some new artifacts to this public apache maven repository so that It gets reflected on nexus, and that my projects can use that. But I am not being able to find a method to do so.